# Loading Rails Assets into an Android Application

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm not even sure how to ask this question... but I will try.

I have both an Android app and a Rails website.  They share the same database.

The crossroads I'm at is that my Android app loads all of its assets directly from an "uploads" folder in the Rails public directory... but the Rails users upload their files to ActiveStorage through the Asset pipeline. (And these, in turn, get loaded onto an Amazon S3 bucket.)

I believe it would make more sense to load the assets the Rails way (and also have them go through AWS so that I can use the cloud), then to have them load directly on the server. But how do I do this?

How do I load something like:

```
https://example.com/assets/favicon-16x16-9edc916cee13c312b1d6afd9cb9e79b21aa4f1bc8d017bb2cf1682fc5c73a6b9.png
```

...on an Android app where it would usually be:

```
https://example.com/uploads/favicon-16x16.png
```

Right now I just have BOTH files there.

Conversely... How would I get users to upload from a Java Android App INTO the Rails asset pipeline?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Of course it does. I just meant that all the apps assets (photos, text, etc...) are loaded from a server... like (almost) every Android app. It connects to an api currently located in the public folder of the Rails site.

Comment: Flagged for trolling.

Comment: `It connects to an api currently located in the public folder of the Rails site` Please give an example.

Comment: `loads all of its assets directly from an "uploads" folder ` For that you do not need an api but only an url to a file. You posted two urls. Unclear which problem you have with those urls. Also unclear which role the same database plays.

Comment: for example: Inside the public folder is a file called "photos.php" this connects to the database and outputs a json with all of the photos and their locations within the "uploads" folder. There's also an "upload.php" for uploading the aforementioned files. What I want to do, instead, is to load and upload those from and to active storage so that both the website and the app are getting and sending the files from and to the same places.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with active storage. Also i do not understand that the website would now use the upload.php and download.php as i would call those scripts the website.

Comment: So your Android app uses the website. Who else uses the website -those php files-? Who else is uploading and downloading?

Comment: The web users are uploading and downloading. (But not using the php files. Only the app uses the php files). Obviously the two were developed separately. But now they need a way to co-exist. Right now there are simply two versions of everything: Two blackapps users (one each in two different Users tables) then if web blackapps uploads a photo of an apple... then that photo gets sent through the asset pipeline. If Android blackapps uploads the same photo... it goes straight to the uploads folder and is retrieved from there. Problem: Web blackapps can't see what Droid Blackapps just uploaded.

Comment: `The web users` You mean those who use a browser like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Yes. People who use web browsers. To access the web site.

Comment: Why dont you just upload files to the same location? I dont understand why that would be a problem.

Comment: Well then you could win 10 points by explaining how that can be done. Like I said... I would like to upload the Android app's photos through the Rails asset pipeline... I just have no idea how to accomplish that. Nor how to get the Android read files that are IN the asset pipeline. How would I teach my app what Rails is calling that photo of the apple. That's the question. Do you have the answer?

Comment: No. As i have no idea what a Rails asset pipeline would be. You do not need to teach Android apps about a pipeline as they are served well. I wonder why if users use a browser cannot upload to and download from the same folder as an Android app does.

Comment: I think you should read the question again... then one more time... then meditate on it. I don't see any trouble connecting the rails App to the Android php system I've setup... but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to do it the other way around. For reasons that I've now thoroughly explained.